# Accidentally changed permissions of /opt, how to undo?

Tags: permissions, directory

I have accidently unlocked a system file with the command:

```
sudo chmod 777 /opt
```

Does anyone know how to undo this action or to lock it again?

Comment: which system file?

Comment: the /opt/ directory

Comment: No problem. Can you mark it accepted please? (toggle the check)

Comment: I have to wait few minutes to mark it, Thanks again :)

Comment: There isn't a way to "undo" this change, but as in the selected answer below, you can modify the permissions to be something safe like `0755`.

Comment: Did you just make this change to the `/opt` folder, or did you make it *recursively* so it affected the `/opt` folder *and all its contents*? If you don't know, please describe, with as much detail as possible, how you made the original change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ownership and permissions:

```
sudo chown root:root /opt; sudo chmod 0755 /opt
```